# Retrieving JSON with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have got this html:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<p class="readMore"></p>
<p class="readMore"></p>
<p class="readMore"></p>
</div>
```

I have got this jquery function:

**UPDATE**

```
  <script>
   function getData() 
   { 
     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/test2/ajax.php",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert("This is my data: "+data);
        },
        error: function( error )
        {
           alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
        });

     } 
   </script>
```

**Result status 0 . on the alert**
Thats the output from  ajax.php page:

```
[{"Article1":"11111111111111111"},{"Article2":"22222222222222222222"},{"Article3":"333333333333"}]
```

I need to take the rows and encode them to a jason..the problem is who do I do that?
And how do I insert the data into the 3 paragraphs on the success of the ajax call.?

Comment: I think you mean JSON, not jason.

Comment: do a find-replace on your editor and replace jason with 'json'

Comment: I did it... need to know if I did it right. is the extraction of data from the database and its encoding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make up JSON use: http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
To put data into paragraphs... one way to go is to assign ID to each paragraph and then traverse response from server and put data in each appropriate paragraphs. There are other ways to do this, but lets try this - you make something and then I (or we) will help to fix problem if you will run into any.

In success use something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('#myDiv').append('<p class="paragraph">' + value[0] + '<br /><br />' + value[1] + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: I cant use ids.. I think that the solution would be to insert to one paragraph and then search for the next

Comment: Sure - you can use other solutions too. Just then at first make empty id="myDiv" (or clean up it in ajax response) and populate it with paragraphs. As i said -there are a lot of ways to get thing done. Try something.

Comment: First, dont forget to change: "datatype: jason," to "datatype: json,".
Second: Check how to handle json data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I updated my anser. you should be able to solve problem with this. If you are not - tell what error did you got.

Comment: I got status 0.. I think the request doesnt even reach the page :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no jason, its called json, or JSON.
Fix that in your code and maybe it will work.

Add content to a div

```
success:function(data){
    $('div').append(data);
}
```

Comment: sure, but I will not complete his code, that's not what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: I need at least some article on how this is done..cause i am clueless with json

Comment: Yeah than I would at least have to know how your json looks like